# How hover on multiple elements but affect just one element in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have `.tabCapture:hover` and it self it work fine it put a box-shadow when I mouse over.

My problem is that over the `.tabCapture` element I have others elements like: `tabFooter`, `tabIcon` and `tabDescription` and when the mouse ran over those the box-shadow disappear.

I'd like to know how I could have the box-shadow even when the mouse is over `tabFooter`, `tabIcon` and `tabDescription` ?

[image]

Comment: Add your code so far you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that there are several other divs present on the the parent ".tabCapture" div. So when the click event takes place on the child divs, the parent div does not receive the hover/mouse events and hence does not trigger the hover selector. To avoid this, you must ignore the mouse events on the child divs and just pass them to the parent div. This can be done by adding the attribute `pointer-events:none` to the css of child divs.

Comment: @Animan It worked perfectly with your solution, Thanks a lot  ! 

Answer (score 0):

Just use a selector that's higher up in the hierarchy, in your case `.tabOuter:hover`.

Comment: I've tried before but it did not work but the @Animan solution worked fine Thanks ! 